# How to get cache stats from @ring.lru wrapping a staticmethod in python?

Tags: python, caching, ring

I'm using `ring` to cache results from a static method, like so:

```
    @ring.lru()
    @staticmethod
    def get_hostname_by_id(object_id):
        return Monkey.get_single_monkey_by_id(object_id).hostname
```

I would like to print the stats of how many misses, hits, and queries I'm getting. Something similar to https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache's `cache_info` method would be useful.

I can see in the internals of `ring`'s LRU implementation the statistics dictionary being updated. However, I can't see how to access this data.

Any ideas?

I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: The `lru_cache` in ring [provides the same method: `cache_info`](https://github.com/youknowone/ring/blob/master/ring/func/lru_cache.py#L119).

Comment: When trying to access it via `print(Monkey.get_hostname_by_id.cache_info())` I'm getting `AttributeError: 'CacheUserInterface' object has no attribute 'cache_info'` @MatsLindh

Answer (score 0):

With @MatsLindh's help, I found it. The LRU cache is accessed via `.storage.backend`. So in my case, it was `Monkey.get_hostname_by_id.storage.backend.cache_info()`.